# Getting "Keyerror : '0' " while creating a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I am trying to create a new column in pandas data frame using a library but for some reason it shows KeyError: '0'

Here is the code,

```
val_1 = [data['OPTION_TYP'] == 'CE',data['OPTION_TYP'] == 'PE']
val_2 = ['c','p']
data['FLAG'] = np.select(val_1,val_2)
r=0.1
data['t'] = data['DTE']/365
idf['LINK'] = idf['DATE'].astype(str) + idf['SYMBOL']
data['LIK'] = data['TIMESTAMP'].astype(str) + data['SYMBOL']
data = data.merge(idf,left_on='LIK',right_on='LINK',how='inner')
data = data[['INSTRUMENT','SYMBOL_x','EXPIRY_DT','STRIKE_PR','OPTION_TYP','CLOSE_x','TIMESTAMP','DTE','t','FLAG','CLOSE_y']]
data.rename(columns = {'CLOSE_x':'OPT_CLOSE' , 'CLOSE_y':'SPOT_CLOSE'} , inplace =True)
data['IV'] = vectorized_implied_volatility(data['OPT_CLOSE'],data['SPOT_CLOSE'],data['STRIKE_PR'],data['t'],r,data['FLAG'])
data
```

The error I am getting

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16596\1435533800.py in <module>
9 data = data[['INSTRUMENT','SYMBOL_x','EXPIRY_DT','STRIKE_PR','OPTION_TYP','CLOSE_x','TIMESTAMP','DTE','t','FLAG','CLOSE_y']]
10 data.rename(columns = {'CLOSE_x':'OPT_CLOSE' , 'CLOSE_y':'SPOT_CLOSE'} , inplace =True)
11 data['IV'] = vectorized_implied_volatility(data['OPT_CLOSE'],data['SPOT_CLOSE'],data['STRIKE_PR'],data['t'],r,data['FLAG'])
12 data

> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py_vollib_vectorized\implied_volatility.py in vectorized_implied_volatility(price, S, K, t, r, flag, q, on_error, model, return_as, dtype, **kwargs)
40     array([0.02621257, 0.12585767])
41     """
42     flag = _preprocess_flags(flag, dtype)
43     price, S, K, t, r, flag = maybe_format_data_and_broadcast(price, S, K, t, r, flag, dtype=dtype)
44     _validate_data(price, S, K, t, r, flag)

> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py_vollib_vectorized\util\data_format.py in _preprocess_flags(flags, dtype)
9 
10 def _preprocess_flags(flags, dtype):
11     return np.array([binary_flag[f] for f in flags], dtype=dtype)
12 
13 

> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py_vollib_vectorized\util\data_format.py in <listcomp>(.0)
9 
10 def _preprocess_flags(flags, dtype):
11     return np.array([binary_flag[f] for f in flags], dtype=dtype)
12 
13
```

KeyError: '0'

The link to library https://github.com/marcdemers/py_vollib_vectorized/blob/main/py_vollib_vectorized/implied_volatility.py

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct the FLAG column is the issues , the key error is being created because the values in the flag column are not recognized by the binary_flag dictionary

Try updating the falg column in your dataframe

```
data['FLAG'] = data['FLAG'].str.lower()
```

Try adding this line before calling the vectorized_implied_volatility() function:

```
data['IV'] = vectorized_implied_volatility(data['OPT_CLOSE'], data['SPOT_CLOSE'], data['STRIKE_PR'], data['t'], r, data['FLAG'])
```

Comment: I updated the column data['FLAG'] = data['FLAG'].str.lower() , but the error continues.